# Unclaimed Foreign Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, china

I do not know where to start.

My grandmother died in July 2011 in Guangzhou, China (she is a Chinese citizen). She owned an apartment, and money in her bank account(s). The biggest problem in this case is she lost her ID prior to dying, and therefore money cannot be withdrawn from the account(s).

My grandmother has 2 sons and 1 daughter, the older son is my father, who died in Canada in 2013, and the younger son, my uncle, died in 2004 in China.

The problem is, my father never had a good relationship with his sister (a.k.a my aunt), and she is apparently too rich to care about the inheritance (but I am not)!

Now, my dead uncle has a daughter (a.k.a my first cousin), she will turn 18 next year, I believe that laws prohibit minors from dealing with inheritances and have to wait until they turn 18?

Now, I am a PR in Canada, and am in university, and my grandmother died without a will, and there is this problem with my aunt not willing to deal with the estate. I do not want to see money that is rightfully mine disappear into nowhere, considering the high cost of being a student in university.

Answer (score 8):

I guess the question implied is "what should I do?".

The answer is: talk to a lawyer familiar with the Chinese inheritance rules.